# Setup mail() inside php.ini in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, apache, email, ubuntu

After fresh Ubuntu 14.04 installation I installed LAMP stack using [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP)
All the installations worked fine but now i am having problem to make PHP mail() work good.

I installed Postfix and configured it as **Satellite system** and passed **smtp.mail.yahoo.it**.
Then changed these settings inside php.ini:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25
```

To this:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = smtp.mail.yahoo.it
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25
auth_username = myUser
auth_password = myPass
```

Then restarted apache.
When i try to use mail() it return TRUE, but i don't receive any email.

How this is possible?
Is there something i am missing?
I am checking apache error log...but nothing there.

Comment: Have you considered trying to use `sendmail` instead?

Comment: Can use postfix as well. But your post looks like you're trying to send it via Yahoo

Comment: i removed poostfix and trying to use sendmail. Found mail.log and it contains thee following messagge: stat=Deferred: Connection refused by alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com